# Errors in GAE dashboard for Channels

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, channel-api

I am using Channel APIs from JS client to connect to GAE server. Even though my channel client is able to successfully get a token and get messages from the server, I keep on getting below error messages in GAE dashboard. I am not sure whether, what am I missing and whether I should be worried.

---

URI - /_ah/channel/disconnected/

Count - 955

% Errors - 100%

---

URI - /_ah/channel/connected/

Count - 943

% Errors - 100%

---

Can anyone please guide me on why am I getting these errors & how to fix them?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Requests to these paths occur when clients connect to or disconnect from the channels you create, if you have channel_presence in your inbound-services in app.yaml/appengine-web.xml. See here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections

or here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections